# Set further attributes of TextView when setText is called

Tags: java, android

I am looking for an easy way to set further attributes of a TextView element based on the input set by TextView.setText().

Specifically, my code currently looks like this:

```
TextView payment;
BigDecimal mBigDecimal;

payment.setText(BigDecimal.toString());
if (mBigDecimal.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == -1) {
    payment.setBackgroundTintList(new ColorStateListStud().getList(ContextCompat.getColor(super.getContext(), R.color.lightred)));
} else if (mBigDecimal.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 1) {
    payment.setBackgroundTintList(new ColorStateListStud().getList(ContextCompat.getColor(super.getContext(), R.color.lightgreen)));
} else {
    payment.setBackgroundTintList(new ColorStateListStud().getList(ContextCompat.getColor(super.getContext(), R.color.transparent)));
}
// ColorStateListStud only holds state_enabled and sets the given color
```

This is copied multiple times over the entirety of my code. so I'd like to streamline that bit best as possible. I want to set the BackgroundTintList based on the BigDecimal value, which I always have at hand when setting the text of a TextView element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two options.

**Create a custom Utils.java class**

You can create a custom and static class which updates the text view for you.

```
public class Utils {

    public static void setText(TextView textView, BigDecimal bigDecimal) {
        if(textView != null && bigDecimal != null) {
            // Get context
            Context context = textView.getContext();

            // Set text
            textView.setText(bigDecimal.toString());

            // Set color
            if (bigDecimal.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == -1) {
                textView.setBackgroundTintList(new ColorStateListStud().getList(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.lightred)));
            } else if (bigDecimal.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 1) {
                textView.setBackgroundTintList(new ColorStateListStud().getList(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.lightgreen)));
            } else {
                textView.setBackgroundTintList(new ColorStateListStud().getList(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.transparent)));
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ERROR", "Error: TextView and/or BigDecimal is null");
        }
}
```

Then, you can just call:

```
Utils.setText(mTextView, mBigDecimal);
```

**Create your own Custom TextView**

```
public class CustomTextView extends TextView {

    public CustomTextView(final Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CustomTextView(final Context context,
            @Nullable final AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CustomTextView(final Context context, @Nullable final AttributeSet attrs,
            final int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public void setText(BigDecimal bigDecimal) {
        setText(bigDecimal.toString());

        // Set color
        if (bigDecimal.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == -1) {
            setBackgroundTintList(new ColorStateListStud().getList(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.lightred)));
        } else if (bigDecimal.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 1) {
            setBackgroundTintList(new ColorStateListStud().getList(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.lightgreen)));
        } else {
            setBackgroundTintList(new ColorStateListStud().getList(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.transparent)));
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in the java side:

```
CustomTextView mTextView = (CustomTextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
mTextView.setText(mBigDecimal);
```

And in your layout.xml:

```
<com.test.CustomTextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, as for creating a CustomTextView class, when I try to create it, extending android.widget.TextView, Android Studio tells me that the class should extend android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView instead. But if I do that and then try to cast a TextView element as my CustomTextView class, Android Studio complains about an unexpected cast. Can I ignore that warning?

Comment: It still compiles, so I guess that answers my question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try `setText()` call at the end

```java
        if (mBigDecimal.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == -1) {
            payment.setBackgroundTintList(new ColorStateListStud().getList(ContextCompat.getColor(super.getContext(), R.color.lightred)));
        } else if (mBigDecimal.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 1) {
            payment.setBackgroundTintList(new ColorStateListStud().getList(ContextCompat.getColor(super.getContext(), R.color.lightgreen)));
        } else {
            payment.setBackgroundTintList(new ColorStateListStud().getList(ContextCompat.getColor(super.getContext(), R.color.transparent)));
        }
        // Only then, call setText() here
        payment.setText(BigDecimal.toString());
```

Comment: Sorry, but that is not what I was asking for the problem I'm having is that the code I posted is duplicated many times throughout my code. I want to streamline my code by having the background tint of TextView elements set when I call setText().